# How to fix JSON indentation in vim?

Tags: javascript, json, vim

In vim, the default indentation for JSON is:

```
{
    "employees": [
    { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
    { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
    { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
    ]
}
```

But what I expect is:

```
{
    "employees": [
        { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
        { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
        { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
    ]
}
```

I did google and tried some vim-json plugins, but none of them fix this issue.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source of the plugins?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. I am a normal vim user, not an advanced user. I don't know how to write plugins. So, no, I haven't tried looking at the source of plugins.

Comment: The indent script contained in [this plugin](https://github.com/jakar/vim-json) does what you ask.

Comment: romainl, thanks a lot for introducing the plugin. that works very well. why don't you answer the question instead of leaving a comment?

Comment: @romainl https://github.com/jakar/vim-json for the win.  now can you find me a decent indent for javascript?

Comment: @Orwellophile, [pangloss's repo](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript) is pretty much the best JS plugin I know of.

Answer (score 45):

Easier way is to just external command as a filter for a selection. e.g.

1. Make a selection
2. Type `:!python -m json.tool`

Comment: This worked for me. And for the whole file, one can do `:%!python -m json.tool`.

Answer (score 26):

romainl recommendation is the preferred way, but sometimes you need to pretty indent JSON text inside some buffer that doesn't have the `json` filetype. I use this nice command:

```
command! -range -nargs=0 -bar JsonTool <line1>,<line2>!python -m json.tool
```

Just run `:JsonTool` and it will pretty print the current line. It can take a range as well:

```
:JsonTool
:'<,'>JsonTool
:10,25JsonTool
```

If you do not have python or prefer a pure vim solution you may be interested in Tim Pope's [jdaddy](https://github.com/tpope/vim-jdaddy) plugin. Jdaddy provides JSON text objects: `aj` and `ij` as well as print print  JSON formatting, e.g. `gqaj`.

Comment: Be careful, if you use python2 it'll sort properties by alphabetical order, so I'd recommend always using python3 when doing this.

Answer (score 16):

You can send to an external tool, as an example, if you have python you can send the content to python's json tool using:

```
:%!python -m json.tool
```

Answer (score 13):

If you have `jq` ([source](https://github.com/stedolan/jq)) available, you can use in the command mode:

```
:%!jq .
```

Answer (score 7):

`python -m json.tool` reorders the position of the JSON object properties, if you have node installed, you can just use this function:

```
function FormatJSON(...) 
  let code="\"
        \ var i = process.stdin, d = '';
        \ i.resume();
        \ i.setEncoding('utf8');
        \ i.on('data', function(data) { d += data; });
        \ i.on('end', function() {
        \     console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(d), null, 
        \ " . (a:0 ? a:1 ? a:1 : 2 : 2) . "));
        \ });\""
  execute "%! node -e " . code 
endfunction
```

Mapped to `f-j` in .vimrc

```
nmap fj :<C-U>call FormatJSON(v:count)<CR>
```

You can also pass a number of spaces for a tab, 2 are the default if you don't specify any.

```
4fj
```

My complete .vimrc is here https://github.com/botverse/.dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc

Answer (score 4):

`gg=G` is what you need if you are using vim.

Comment: +1 because this is good if the JSON object is already on different lines, but the `json.tool` method handles objects that are all clumped on one line.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example in Ruby:

```
:%! ruby -rjson -e "print JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(ARGF.read))"
```

(https://gist.github.com/zinovyev/c4b6ec3c24670278adfebfb9ecced84b)

Answer (score 1):

Add this statement to `/etc/vim/vimrc`:

```
autocmd Filetype json setlocal ts=2 sw=2 expandtab
```

It will force json presentation with 2 spaces tab, besides defining tab behaviour for such file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python to format json:

```
:%!python -m json.tool
```

Besides, there are several other tools can be used, such as `jsbeautify`, `prettydiff`,`prettier`,`jq` and `fixjson`.

See https://medium.com/@codevalues/how-to-explore-a-json-with-thousands-of-lines-using-vim-7f9d1ec550dc  for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to @ivanleoncz (the best and simplest one) but with some extras (also put on /etc/vim/vimrc or ~/.vimrc):

```
au! BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.{json} set filetype=json foldmethod=indent
autocmd FileType json setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab modeline autoindent smartindent
```