# How to auto format JSON on save in Vim

Tags: json, vim, format, lint

To be honest `go` has spoiled me. With `go` I got used to having a strict formatting standard that is being enforced by my editor (vim) and is almost accepted and followed by everybody else on the team and around the world.

I wanted to format JSON files on save the same way.

Question: How to auto format/indent/lint json files on save in vim.

Comment: Related post: [How to fix json indentation in vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16620835/438329)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks mMontu and Jose B, this is what I ended up doing:

**WARNING** this will overwrite your buffer. So if you OPEN a json file that already has a syntax error, you will lose your whole file (or can lose it).

Add this line to your `~/.vimrc`

```
" Ali: to indent json files on save
autocmd FileType json autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> %!python -m json.tool
```

you need to have python on your machine, of course.

**EDIT:** this next one should not overwrite your buffer if your json has error. Which makes it the correct answer, but since I don't have a good grasp of Vim script or shell for that matter, I present it as an experimental thing that you can try if you are feeling lucky. It may depend on your shell too. You are warned.

```
" Ali: to indent json files on save
autocmd FileType json autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> %!python -m json.tool 2>/dev/null || echo <buffer>
```

Comment: Is there a way to update this to prevent writing to the buffer if the json is not well formatted. Bonus points for raising an error in one of the helper windows.

Comment: Testing it with well formatted json throws an error. I don't enough vim script to debug the error hence why I am asking here. The first response that doesn't check about obliterating the buffer works perfectly for well formatted json.

Comment: @NeoZenith What is the error? what shell you are using? on what OS? what Vim version?

Comment: **OS**: OSX 10.10.5, **VimVer**:7.4 **ErrMsg**: syntax error near unexpected token ')' `(%!python -m json.tool 2>/dev/null || echo <buffer>)`

Answer (score 116):

In one command, try this:

```
execute '%!python -m json.tool' | w
```

You could then add you own key binding to make it a simpler keystroke. Of course, for this to work, you need to have Python installed on your machine.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `| w` here? Why not just:  `:%!python -m json.tool`?

Comment: `|w` just saves the buffer, without it you would get the json formatted but the changes would be unsaved. It depends on what you want I guess.

Comment: Ah right, I see, I was confused as I thought it was piping into the bash [w](http://linux.die.net/man/1/w) command. But yeah, `:write` makes sense. cheers!

Comment: I keep getting `Error occured at line 1`, but when I cat the same file into the json.tool at command-line, it works. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 90):

If you are keen on using external tool and you are doing some work with json, I would suggest using the `jq`:

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Then, you can execute `:%!jq .` inside vim which will replace the current buffer with the output of jq.

Comment: For someone looking for a Windows way of doing it, change the single quotes to double quotes:  `:%!jq "."` assuming you downloaded the windows version of jq, and renamed it from `jq-win64.exe` to `jq.exe` (similar for 32 bit version).  Also, make sure it's in your path.

Comment: I did not have to put quotations around `.`, `:%! jq .` works for me, or  `:%! jq --indent 4 .`

Comment: I prefer `jq` over the python command because python might change content based on encoding. E.g. `{"test": "ü"}`  where `"ü"` becomes `"\u00fc"` after `:%!python -m json.tool`

Answer (score 26):

`%!python -m json.tool`

or

`%!python -c "import json, sys, collections; print json.dumps(json.load(sys.stdin, object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict), ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)"`

you can add this to your vimrc:

`com! FormatJSON %!python -m json.tool`

than you can use `:FormatJson` format json files

Comment: If you want to disable `ensure_ascii` or use your own `indent`, you could use `com! FormatJSON %!python -m json.tool --no-ensure-ascii --indent 4`. As `python -m json.tool --help` suggests.

Answer (score 6):

A search for JSON plugins on vim.org returned this:

[jdaddy.vim : JSON manipulation and pretty printing](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4863)

It has the following on description:

> `gqaj` "pretty prints" (wraps/indents/sorts keys/otherwise cleans up)
>   the JSON construct under the cursor.

If it does the formatting you are expecting then you could create an `autocmd BufWritePre` to format when saving.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution. It doesn't *exactly* address the question part of "on save" but if you perform this action before save it will output errors you can then fix before save.

Also, it depends on only one external tool -- `jq` -- which has become the gold standard of unix shell JSON processing tools. And which you probably already have installed (macOS and Linux/Unix only; idk how this would behave in Windows)

Basically, it's just:

```
ggVG!jq '.'
```

That will highlight the entire JSON document then run it through `jq` which will just parse it for correctness, reformat it (e.g. fix any indents, etc), and spit the output back into the Vim editor.

If you want to parse only part of the document, you can highlight that part manually by pressing `v` or `V` and then run

```
!jq '.'
```

The benefit here is that you can fix subsections of your document this way.

Comment: Faster—`:%!jq '.'`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble yeah I saw that in an earlier answer but I didn't see it until I had already typed out 95% of my own answer. so i submitted my answer anyway.

Comment: you don't even have to put the dot, it is implicit

Answer (score 3):

**Vim Autoformat**

https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat

There is this Vim plugin which supports multiple auto format and indent schemes as well as extending with custom formatters per filetype.

https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat#default-formatprograms

**Note:**

You will need to have `nodejs` and `js-beautify` installed as `vim-autoformat` uses these as the default external tool.

`npm install -g js-beautify`

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use [coc-format-json](https://github.com/gera2ld/coc-format-json).

Answer (score 1):

I did some organizing (though some of it had nothing to do with vim) and to write the script by yourself on the [neovim](https://neovim.io/)!

## solution1: neovim

### 1-1: write the script by yourself

Neovim allows Python3 plugins to be defined by placing python files or packages in `rplugin/python3/` in a `runtimepath` folder)

in my case

```
- init.vim
- rplugin/python3/[your_py_file_set].py
- rplugin/python3/fmt_file.py
```

The `fmt_file.py` as following

```
# rplugin/python3/fmt_file.py

import pynvim
import json


@pynvim.plugin
class Plugin:
    __slots__ = ('vim',)

    def __init__(self, vim):
        self.vim = vim

    @pynvim.command('FormatJson', nargs='*', range='')
    def format_json(self, args, rg):
        """
        USAGE::

            :FormatJson
        """
        try:
            buf = self.vim.current.buffer
            json_content: str = '\n'.join(buf[:])
            dict_content: dict = json.loads(json_content)
            new_content: str = json.dumps(dict_content, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
            buf[:] = new_content.split('\n')
        except Exception as e:
            self.vim.current.line = str(e)
```

afterwards run: `:UpdateRemotePlugins` from within `Nvim` once, to generate the necessary Vimscript to make your Plugin available. (**and you best restart the neovim**)

and then, you open the JSON file that one you want to format and typing: `:FormatJson` in the command. all done.

---

don't forget to tell vim where is your python

```
" init.vim

let g:python3_host_prog = '...\python.exe''
```

and `pip install pynvim`

### 1-2: use tool.py

where `tool.py` is located on the `Lib/json/tool.py`

`:%!python -m json.tool`

## solution2: command line

If you already install the python, and you can open the command line:

```
python -m json.tool "test.json" >> "output.json"
```

## solution3: python

I write a simple script for those things.

```
"""
USAGE::

    python fmt_file.py fmt-json "C:\test\test.json"
    python fmt_file.py fmt-json "C:\test\test.json"  --out_path="abc.json"
    python fmt_file.py fmt-json "test.json"  --out_path="abc.json"
"""

import click  # pip install click
from click.types import File
import json
from pathlib import Path


@click.group('json')
def gj():
    ...


@gj.command('fmt-json')
@click.argument('file_obj', type=click.File('r', encoding='utf-8'))
@click.option('--out_path', default=None, type=Path, help='output path')
def format_json(file_obj: File, out_path: Path):
    new_content = ''
    with file_obj as f:
        buf_list = [_ for _ in f]
        if buf_list:
            json_content: str = '\n'.join(buf_list)
            dict_content: dict = json.loads(json_content)
            new_content: str = json.dumps(dict_content, indent=4, sort_keys=True)

    if new_content:
        with open(out_path if out_path else Path('./temp.temp_temp.json'),
                  'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(new_content)


def main():
    for register_group in (gj,):
        register_group()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can search for 'vim-json-line-format' plugin, Open a file in `Normal mode`, move your cursor on the json line, use `<leader>pj` to show formated json by print it, use `<leader>wj` could change the text to formatted json.
Invalid json can not format!

Answer (score 0):

**Use ALE to auto-format on save**

[Configure ALE to format JSON](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/38595/11022)

add the following to **.vim/vimfiles/after/ftplugin/json.vim**:

```
let b:ale_fix_on_save = 1 " Fix files when they are saved.
```