# Large, one-line text file is not shown correctly by Vim

Tags: vim

I would like to use vim to open the a big file, that consist of one, long line. The content of the file is JSON, but what I see on the screen doesn't resemble JSON at all: 
[image: this is how vim shows the content of the file]

The file size is ~115kB.

The file mentioned is available under the following link: http://live.leanpoker.org/api/tournament/5587222ded8a3e0003000002/game

What I've tried so far:

1. I've tried using `:set nowrap` but that doesn't help. I've also tried playing with `set display+=lastline` with no luck as well.
2. I am able to see the content of the file properly when using built-in editor/viewer in mc (midnight commander) or kate (but kate complains on line exceeding maximum lenght).
3. My `.vimrc` is extremely simple, but I've tried to open the file with `vanilla vim`. There was no change in the way the file content was presented.

My OS is Kubuntu:

`Linux xps 3.13.0-57-generic #95-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 09:28:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

My vim version is:

`VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:59)
Included patches: 1-52
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
+balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
+browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     +tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
+clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      +toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con_gui  +lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      +X11
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xim
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      -sniff           +xsmp_interact
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    +xpm
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz     -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/usr/include/tcl8.6  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1

Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E  -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfreetype   -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl  -L/usr/lib -llua5.2 -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl/5.18/CORE -lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lcrypt -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ltcl8.6 -ldl -lz -lpthread -lieee -lm -lruby-1.9.1 -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm  -L/usr/lib`

Comment: The link you gave correctly opens a JSON file in the browser.  Do you know what the _encoding_ of the file in question is?  Could this be the reason why VIM is choking on it?

Comment: Here is how you can reload a file in Vim using a different encoding: `:e ++enc=<encoding>`

Comment: Are you looking for [pretty printing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16625961/438329)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for pointing that out. I had tried that myself, as I thought the encoding was a problem. That was not the problem thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is actually gzipped. Your two other editors automatically recognize and unzip it transparently; VIM does not. The web site serves it gzipped and some HTTP downloading tools won't decompress it automatically.

Just `gunzip < yourfile > yourfile.right`.

Comment: A bit of advice for the future: text editors are not goid tools for looking at what a file really contains at the byte level. They have gotten too smart. Use programs like `od` for that. The utility called `file` is also useful.

Comment: omg... I am just so... embarrassed by not figuring this out myself. mc's built-in editor surprised me, being able to show the file properly, and would have never guessed that mc is capable of unpacking (ungzipping) files automatically. If I gzip had something similar as "PK!" at the beginning of the file :) Thank you for your answer! Thanks for pointing me to `od`!